# extract alert from urban airship userinfo

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

Inside the method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
}
```

How do I extract the `alert` value from the dictionary UserInfo? I believe the dictionary might look something like

```
  {
    "_" = "l0-mgGElEeKbHAAbIbyL6A";
    aps =     {
        alert = "Manual: IOM update 2013-01-17T20:14:42-08:00";
        badge = 0;
    };
    operation = update;
    tab = manuals;
}
```

Is this really always the case? Or **does Urban Airship provide a method for doing this?** which would really be ideal.

**UPDATE**

Based on feedback by @Spynet

It seems that by **alert** what I really mean is the actual text message, which in the case where the `alert` itself is a dictionary may be called the `body` of the alert. All the same, does Urban Airship provide a method for extracting such information? Or must I roll out my own? If my own, has anyone done this successfully? Thanks.

Comment: read the manual by apple and refined your question https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW15

Comment: sorry i didn't integrated that much deeper but if you integrated that means, you should need to know the keys based on that only you can able proceed

Comment: @Spynet So there is no urban airship general method that you know of? I'll keep digging.

Comment: your the one sending the message from server or someone?

Comment: Yes, I am the one. Right now the alert is just a string (ie. the body). So I could extract on that. But I was hoping for a general solution that would take other configurations into account. Something that urban airship might have taken care of.

Comment: are you going to use the urban airship?

Answer (score 0):

Actually urban airship does take care of it for you. Simple implement the protocol `UAPushNotificationDelegate` and method

```
- (void)displayNotificationAlert:(NSString *)alertMessage;
```